# Json being displayed instead on Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

```
**ChatController**
```

am new to laravel and vue i just got this and wanted learn some new skills.
This controller queries a single user from my model called PostRequest i use one-to-one relationship

```
class ChatController extends Controller
 {
    public function getMessages()
   {

    return view('user.message'); //response()->json($contacts);
   }
   public function get()
  {
    $email = Auth::user()->email;
    $contacts = PostRequest::with('user')->where([['email', $email]])->orderBy('id','DESC')- 
    >first()->user;
    return response()->json($contacts, 200);
   
 }
```

}

**ChatComponent**

```
<template>
  <div class="chat-app">
    <Conversation :contact="selectedContact" :messages="messages" />
    <ContactsList
        v-if="contacts"
        :contacts="contacts"
    />
 </div>
 </template>
  <script>
   import Conversation from './Conversation';
   import ContactsList from './ContactsList';
    export default {
     props: {
        user: {
          type: Object,
          required: true
      }
  },
  data() {
      return {
          selectedContact: null,
          messages: [],
          contacts: null
      }
  },
  mounted() {
    //console.log('LoggedIn User',this.user);
    axios.get('/user/contacts').then((response) => {
       // console.log('contact', response.data);
        if(this.contacts == undefined){return}
        this.contacts = response.data;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
},
  components: {Conversation, ContactsList}
 }
</script>
```

**ContactListComponent**

this component will pass my user data into message.blade

```
<template>
<div class="contacts-list" >
    <ul v-for="contact in contacts" :key="contact.id">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, autem.</p>
        <li >
            <div class="avatar">
                <img :src="contact.user.reqPhoto" :alt="contact.user.name">
            </div>
            <div class="contact">
                <p class="name">{{contact.user.name}}</p>
                <p class="email">{{contact.user.email}}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>
<script>
 export default {
   props: {
      contacts: {
        type: [],
        default: null
        }
     }
 }
```

**message blade**
this blade file recieves the user data from vue, have tried to view page source nothing is coming in

```
<section class="inbox">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Chat with:</div>
                    <div class="card-body" id="app">
                        <chat-component :contacts="contacts"></chat-component>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @include('layouts.sidenav')
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**web Routes**

i also tried using same routes its still returns same json file even after trying different browsers

```
Route::get('/user/messages', [ChatController::class, ('getMessages')])->name('msg');
Route::get('/user/contacts', [ChatController::class, ('get')]);
```

**app.js**

require('./bootstrap');

```
window.Vue = require('vue').default;

Vue.component('chat-component', 
require('./components/ChatComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component("Conversation", 
require("./components/Conversation.vue").default);
Vue.component('contact', 
require('./components/ContactsList.vue').default);
Vue.component("MessagesFeed", 
require("./components/MessageFeed.vue").default);
Vue.component("MessageComposer", 
require("./components/MessageComposer.vue").default);

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
});
```

Comment: You are saying *"this blade file recieves the user data from vue"*. So are you trying to send the response from axios again to the backend? You receive the list of contacts using axios and want to render a blade template with the result? How does the blade template know what a `chat-component` is? Shouldn't you render this in the frontend instead?

Comment: @peter thanks for your response, i have a contactListComponent where i recieve all the user data then send it to the message.blade. But Kindly help explain better like i said am a newbie in this thanks

Comment: Well that's what I was asking. Are you trying to use a Laravel blade template with data from the frontend? No, render your data entirely in Vue. If this blade template is from the frontend maybe you just forgot to add your component to `components`? [see vue docs: registering components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration)

Comment: @peter yes iam trying to use a Laravel blade template with data from the frontend, however i registered the component in app.js, i just added app.js you can check thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you can mix Laravel and Vue like that. When `<chat-component :contacts="contacts"></chat-component>` is returned in the HTML, Vue doesn't know it should initialize that as a component. I would say you should request the side navigation from a blade file, otherwise stay with Vue for the layout.

Comment: @peter i was actually following up with this guy on [Youtube] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sXmfwnxfjA&t=20s) and i can't figure out where i got it wrong.

Comment: Ah okay. Should have included that in the question also, that would help. The YouTube video mentions [the chat app's GitHub repo](https://github.com/AfikDeri/Messenger-App-VueJS-and-Laravel). Can't you compare your application to that? Have you watched [the other parts](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJpBh2VJhy5x2GKfkfIcn0r6P6uLat7xR)?

Comment: @Peter have not watched the other parts of the video and have not tried to check the repo but it's a good idea, i will check to confirm thanks alot